# LilyPond - Grace note too close to the barline

Tags: notation, sheet-music, lilypond

Lilypond places the grace notes very close to the barline (see image). Is it possible to create more room between the barline and the notes?

[image]

Comment: I'm puzzled by the complex key signature: is the effect different in C major?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
{
  \key ces \major
  \bar ".|:"
  \grace \tweak extra-spacing-width #'(-1 . 0) as'8 \glissando
  ces''2
}
```

or

```
{
  \key ces \major
  \temporary\override Staff.BarLine.space-alist.first-note = #'(fixed-space . 6)
  \bar ".|:"
  \grace as'8 \glissando
  \revert Staff.BarLine.space-alist.first-note
  ces''2
}
```